# Detect words and letters typed in input and sort other elements (text in div) with same letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make an input, in which you type words or letters to sort some kind of elements. For example: there are divs with different words in them, and when you type something in the input immediately sort the divs which have the same letters as in the input...

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Sort by...">

<div class="sortable-items">
    <div>dogs</div>
    <div>cats</div>
    <div>dogs</div>
    <div>dogs</div>
    <div>cats</div>
    <div>cats</div>
    <div>dogs</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sort, or *filter*? This question/interaction doesn't make sense for sorting.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If yes please share it with us and we'll help you with that.

Comment: Sort by the words/letters, typed in the input.

Comment: Well I have made researches only, but I can't seem to figure out how to structure the code.

Comment: Do you want to sort so the best matches appear first? Or do you want to show only the items that match the input? so if you type "dog", should only the dogs be visible, or should the dogs appear first on the list?

Comment: While you type (onChange) in the input, the text content sorts by the letters in the input. So dynamically show the sorted items while typing in the input. And as for the dogs, I want to show only the matches not the whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you listen for the keyup event on the input, the function will call every time you type or remove a letter. You can then check if the input matches any of the divs' value, and hide/show it based on that.

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){
    var searchTerm = $(this).val();
    $(".sortable-items div").each(function(){
        if($(this).text().match(searchTerm)){
            $(this).show();
        }else{
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

You can test it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h9sck2nh/1/

Comment: Thank you very much, as I read through the code, I understood how easy it was. I really appreciate your help. :)