# user input text as button to change hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'd like to change the url-hash-part when a certain term was typed in by a user into a textarea. 
a kind of text bottom.
my background: art school. so almost no scripting skills.
and not at all javascript. 
but took a lot of time to get even here.

what i've done so far:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="textarea" placeholder="text buttons... " id="search">
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<div class="text-buttons" type="submit" style="visibility: hidden">
    <div>info</div>
    <div>essay</div>
    <div>back</div>
</div>

<script>
$('#search').keyup(function(){
    var searchTerm = $(this).val(); //user inputted
    $(".text-buttons div").each(function(){ //loop through the list
        if($(this).text().match(searchTerm)){ //check if list item contains the search term
            term = $(this)//store the matched term in a variable
            }
                if ( term === info )//check if the term is «info».
                    location.hash = "part2" //change the anchor part 
                    window.onhashchange = function(); //calls he hashchange
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

just tried to change this code:
[an answer to another question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302151/detect-words-and-letters-typed-in-input-and-sort-other-elements-text-in-div-wi)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
<input type="textarea" placeholder="text buttons... " id="search">

<div class="text-buttons" style="visibility: hidden">
    <div>info</div>
    <div>essay</div>
    <div>back</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#search').keyup(function () {
            var searchTerm = $(this).val(); //user inputted
            var term = '';
            $(".text-buttons div").each(function () { //loop through the list
                if ($(this).text().match(searchTerm)) { //check if list item contains the search term
                    term = $(this).text();//store the matched term in a variable
                }
            });
            if (term === 'info')//check if the term is «info».
                window.location.hash = "part2" //change the anchor part
            window.onhashchange = function () {
            }; //calls he hashchange
        });
    });

</script>
```